# Can't acces via HTTPS IIS7

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-7

i bought an SSL certificate and followed a guide to import the SSL to my IIS 7, then, i stablished the bindings

> https  All unassigned 443
> Hostname ( Cant write any text here)
> SSL: customerwebsite.com (Not the real URL)

Restarted the website and tried to access via https to the site but a "Connection is not secure" advert is shown on the browser. I tried to see more information about the cert and it shows information of another SSL, it shows that the SSL was issued to TP-LINK, it doesnt show the information of the SSL that i have installed.

Do you know please what can i do in this case? This is so important. I need to install that SSL.

Thanks for all the help.

I Installed the SSL and then configured the bindings.

Comment: Are you trying to host a web site on your own machine? (Similar to https://halfblood.pro/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef)

Comment: Not sure how you imported SSL into IIS and bindings. Does your new certificate appear in the list of server certificates? Did you bind the correct certificate? Have you tried reinstalling and configuring your SSL certificate?

Comment: Hi, yes the SSL appears in the list of server certificates and i have set the binding correctly. I've removed and installed the SSL again but when trying to access to the website using the https protocol it keeps showing a certificate error and shows the SSL from TP-link not the Sectigo SSL that we bought

Comment: An SSL certificate error occurs when a web browser cannot verify the SSL certificate installed on a site. Instead of connecting the user to your website, the browser will display an error message warning the user that the website may not be safe. Could you please post details about the certificate error?